# Get Maximum Performance of a loop

Tags: c#, cpu

I am trying to calculate on a BigInteger variable then add the result to the database .

What happen is sth like this :

```
            for (BigInteger i = 0; i < ABigIntegerVariable; i++)
        {
            // add to db and calculate on a BigInteger
        }
```

So the problem is when I see CPU Usage on Task Manager it is only about 8% !
and this loop takes about 1 hour or more !!!

So it is not necessary for me to use computer while it is trying to calculate and add to database .

Would you pls tell me how to use the CPU with a high percentage of calculation and improve this process to have a faster calculation ?!

Thank you

Comment: What about Multithreading? Have you ever got in touch with it?

Comment: How do you "add to db"? I believe main bottleneck is the latency and IPC between your process and sql server (or any). What about adding items to DB in batch? That will increase the performance significantly.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel +1 yeah ! thank you ... it is a good way. I test it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is for multiple reasons:

**1**. your for loop runs on single thread,
 **2**. you insert data into database in each iteration, instead of doing it in batch after processing of the loop is finished.

**Proposed solutions**:

**1**. You can try to use **Parallel.For** method to speed up the **1**.
    reason.

Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx

**2**. You can move code responsible for saving the data from your for loop out of it to speed up the **2**. reason.

Answer (score 2):

you may use Task/Thread if the code inside the loop can run concurrent

```
        for (BigInteger i = 0; i < ABigIntegerVariable; i++)
        {
            Thread thread= new Thread(m =>
            {
                //TODO: do something spectacular with i
            });
            thread.Start(i);
        }
```

Comment: As BigInteger was introduced by FW4, we can suppose OP use FW 4. So rather than Thread he could also use Task from TPL. It would give better management of threading. Because depending of ABigIntegerVariable, your proposal may lead to a potentially VERY huge thread count ;)